# Imperative mapping of a pandas DataFrame to a single table row in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have an class which I am trying to map using [imperative mapping with SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-a-k-a-classical-mappings).

One of the attributes of this class when it is instanced is a pandas DataFrame such that

```
class ClassToBeMapped:
    def __init__(self, name: str, data_table: pandas.DataFrame):
        self.name = name
        self.data_table = data_table
```

where `data_table` is of structure

```
   foo  bar
0  0.1  0.2
1  4.0  5.0
2  0.7  0.8
```

In the ORM, I have so far defined the SQLAlchemy Table for ClassToBeMapped as

```
Table(
    'mapped_classes',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('name', String(255))
)
```

I would like to map another Table which stores the 2D DataFrame `data_table` as a single row in the database such that

```
Table(
    'data_tables',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('assoc_name', String(255), ForeignKey('mapped_clases.name')),
    Column('foo_0', Float),
    Column('foo_1', Float),
    Column('foo_2', Float),
    Column('bar_0', Float),
    Column('bar_1', Float),
    Column('bar_2', Float)
)
```

How would I correctly declared a SQLAlchemy Table so that when I map `data_table` to it using [`map_imperatively`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.registry.map_imperatively), SQLAlchemy knows that each of the columns in the SQLAlchemy Table refer to a single value from a location in the database? (e.g. `Column('foo_0', Float)` corresponds to `data_table.loc[0, 'foo']`)

Note: pandas.DataFrame.to_sql is not appropriate here as the 2D DataFrame contains data associated with a single object, not multiple separate rows of data.